# check that new username is in neither of two separate tables

Tags: mysql, database, select

I would like to make sure that a certain user isn't existing already in my system. I have two tables:

- one with the confirmed users (xymply_users)
- one with the unconfirmed users (xymply_newusers).

I want to check the guy that's signed up right now has selected a username not already in either of the tables. I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM xymply_users, xymply_newusers 
WHERE xymply_users.user ='test' 
OR xymply_newusers.user ='test'
```

but if there's a user 'test' in xymply_users it won't show up with this query, why not I'm wondering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UNION`!

```
(SELECT 1 FROM xymply_users WHERE xymply_users.user ='test')
UNION
(SELECT 1 FROM  xymply_newusers WHERE xymply_newusers.user ='test')
```

Will give 1 record if the user exists, 2 records if it exists in both, no records if the user doesn't exist.

`SELECT 1` is just an optimization; it's faster than `SELECT *` (`SELECT *` is usually always wrong)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM xymply_users.u, xymply_newusers.nu where u.username = nu.username
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM xymply_users.u, xymply_newusers.nu where u.username = 'username' AND nu.username = 'username' AND u.username = nu.username
```

Comment: Well, it will identify if the same username exists in __both__ tables, but OP wants to see if username exists in __either__ table

Comment: A username in xymply_users will equal a username in xymply_newusers, obviously if that happens it will exits on both tables.

Comment: Alright, I'm clearly getting old and senile because I'm confusing my ANDs and my XORs... I got the impression that OP wanted XOR, not AND.... so where does his "test" name come into this?